# Complexity of queries and old-school databases

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I recently started working in a big government organization. I studied Software Development for 4 years. In that time we glanced over the basic old school database usage and database-first design and I can write a basic query, but we did not go into very complex database design. We focused more on the newer technologies such as code-first entity framework and model-first etc.

Now, the various IT policies at my organization just about makes any change or advancement of techniques and technologies used impossible. Just this morning I got a works request to resolve an issue where a web app calling info from a database is timing out. I quickly determined that the code-behind of the web page is calling a stored procedure which is querying a table with over 200k records, so I opened it up to try and see if I can gauge the efficiency of the procedure.

The complexity of the procedure is way beyond my capabilities to reproduce and almost too complex to even understand! I have the DB administrator helping me out by adding indexes to tables, so I won't be asking for a technical solution here. Next, have a look at the stored procedure in question before I continue:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_RandomisationResultCount]
  @noOfRows INT,
  @subcouncil INT,
  @wards VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
  @suburbs VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
  @courts VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
  @skills VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
  @isDisabled VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
  @hasQualification VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
  @gender VARCHAR(1) = NULL,
  @age INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SELECT  COUNT(tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID) resultCount
FROM tblJobSeekerDetails LEFT JOIN tbl_lnk_JobSeeker_OtherSkills 
ON tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID = tbl_lnk_JobSeeker_OtherSkills.JobSeeker_ID LEFT JOIN tblOtherSkills 
ON tbl_lnk_JobSeeker_OtherSkills.OtherSkillsID = tblOtherSkills.OtherSkillsID LEFT JOIN tblJobSeekerEmploymentHistory
ON tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID = tblJobSeekerEmploymentHistory.JobSeekerID
WHERE (tblJobSeekerDetails.SubCouncilID = @subcouncil)
            AND ((WardID IN (SELECT s.Item                       FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@wards, ',') s)) OR (@wards IS NULL))
            AND ((Suburb IN (SELECT s.Item                       FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@suburbs, ',') s)) OR (@suburbs IS NULL))
            AND ((RoadType IN (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@courts, ',') s)) OR (@courts IS NULL))
            AND ((tblOtherSkills.OtherSkillsID in (SELECT s.Item FROM ufn_SplitIntArray(@skills, ',') s)) OR (@skills IS NULL))
            AND ((Disability = @isDisabled) OR (@isDisabled IS NULL))
            AND ((HasTertiaryQualification = @hasQualification) OR (@hasQualification IS NULL))
            AND ((Gender = @gender) OR (@gender IS NULL))
            AND ((ISNUMERIC(IdentityNumber) = 1 AND 
                  IdentityNumber NOT LIKE '%.%' AND 
                  DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) - (CONVERT(INT, '19' + SUBSTRING(IdentityNumber, 1, 2), 100)) = @age) OR (@age IS NULL))
            AND (TypeID = 1)--Jobseekers only
            AND (tblJobSeekerDetails.IsExcludedFromRandomisation <> 1 OR tblJobSeekerDetails.IsExcludedFromRandomisation IS NULL)--Explicitly excluded jobseekers
            AND (tblJobSeekerDetails.JobSeeker_ID not in (SELECT DISTINCT tj.JobSeeker_ID --Exclude Jobseekers as per stipulated exclusion periods
                                                          FROM tblJobSeekerDetails tj INNER JOIN tblJobSeekerEmploymentHistory wh
                                                          ON tj.JobSeeker_ID = wh.JobSeekerID
                                                          WHERE ((DATEDIFF(DAY, wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo) <= 14 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo, GETDATE()) <= 3 ))
                                                          OR
                                                          ((DATEDIFF(DAY, wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo) > 14 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, wh.DateOfEmploymentTo, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 4 AND 6))
                                                          OR
                                                          (GETDATE() BETWEEN wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom AND wh.DateOfEmploymentTo)
                                                          OR (wh.DateOfEmploymentFrom > GETDATE() OR wh.DateOfEmploymentTo > GETDATE())
                                                          GROUP BY tj.JobSeeker_ID))
END
```

Now, this is enough to terrify me. I can understand in overview what its supposed to do, but going about making it more efficient would be impossible for me at present time. The only reason I was asked to look at this issue was because the developer responsible for the application is booked off sick today. My question is, is this something that is usually created with the sql knowledge of the developer, or is some kind of tool employed to assist in creating such monstrous sql?

Comment: Man, where did you study? FIrst, that is not a super complex SP (and 200.000 rows is tiny). Second, for studying 4 years and not learning how to use a database (and no, Entity Framework / Code First are not replacements for learning basic SQL) is wasted time. There is a lot of things you can not even express in EF that you can do in SQL. By most standards, that above IS a basic query. Not a "total beginner no clue SQL" query, but not really that complex either.

Comment: Oh, and another thing. The complexity of this query has NOTHING to do with "old school". In EF you would have a similar complexity. Which translates to "you never did really more than totally trivial queries in 4 years". Even using EF you may end up joining a dozen tables and having a page or two of conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typical procedure. It was probably hand-coded.

The procedure seems to be doing a search based on a number of search parameters (probably from a search form in the application).

This kind of query is often hard for the optimizer since it lacks a key search term (or has different key search terms in different calls).

The best optimisation for this particular query would probably be a full table scan, so check if any indexes have been added recently and try removing them. Note that the index was probably added for a reason, so removing an index may introduce performance problems in other parts of the application.

If that fails, you should check the query plan.

Answer (score 1):

Actually no, there are serious issues here.

First, please provid the queryp lan.

But second - WITH RECOMPILE hint is needed. This SP Has a lot of different query paths depending on parameters but that is not expressed - the first call will determine the query path, regardless how sensible. The standard (basic knowledge) way around that is to add hints to the query what to optimize for - or ell the compiler to not reuse plans, which is what WITH RECOMPILE does.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx

This is not old school - sorry. This type of SP was rotten 15 years ago. It is one thing where any higher level query framework shines (EF / LINQ being one, but hey, I used something similar around 1990, no joke, so do not say "modern" to something going back way longer than you learned programming). SQL - especially in SP's - is hard to handle variable query requirements.